# In.readObject continues reading in same object when a new object is received

Tags: java, tcp, udp

The receiver will receive files via both TCP and UDP to the receiver.

The file storage location can be chosen by the receiver.

*If the incoming data is larger than the buffer size, the data is received in -multiple packets, and each packet is stored in the buffer one after the other.

@sources

*/

import java.io.*; import java.net.DatagramPacket; import java.net.DatagramSocket; import java.net.InetAddress; import java.net.ServerSocket; import java.net.Socket; import java.nio.file.Files; import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.Arrays; import java.util.Comparator; import java.util.HashMap; import java.util.Map; import java.util.TreeMap; import java.util.Map.Entry;

/*TODO *measure incoming packet percentage, but need tcp implemented *process data received

-API call to receive file location where to save

*/ public class Receiver {

private DatagramSocket socket; private byte[] buffer; private int bufferSize; private int port; private long totalBytesReceived; private long totalfilesize; private String filelocation; private boolean connected; private boolean connected1; int r; private Socket tcpSocket; private ObjectInputStream in; private ObjectOutputStream out; private InetAddress addr; private int udpPort; private int tcpPort; Boolean missingpackets; ServerSocket serverSocket; ByteArrayInputStream inStream; ObjectInputStream objInStream; private File f; DatagramPacket packet; numberedPacket receivedNumberedPacket; int length, burstCounter, packetSize, k; ArrayList<Integer> packetNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); ArrayList<Integer> packetnumbersreceived = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// buffer size is fixed size of packet // burst size is number of packets sent in burst public Receiver(int tcpPort, int udpPort) throws Exception { this.tcpPort = tcpPort; this.socket = new DatagramSocket(udpPort); // this.buffer = new byte[bufferSize]; this.connected = false;

}

// Not using anymore // public void receive() throws Exception { // DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, bufferSize); // socket.receive(packet);

// // Process received packet // byte[] data = packet.getData(); // int offset = packet.getOffset(); // int length = packet.getLength(); // InetAddress address = packet.getAddress(); // int port = packet.getPort(); // long percentageloaded = 0; // // work out percentage of file received // percentageloaded = totalBytesReceived / totalfilesize; // updateGUI(percentageloaded); // // Print packet information // System.out.println("Received packet:"); // System.out.println("Address: " + address.getHostAddress()); // System.out.println("Port: " + port); // System.out.println("Data: " + new String(data, offset, length)); // System.out.println("Percentage of file received:" + percentageloaded); // }

public boolean connect() {

```
try {
    // Creating a server socket and binding it to the port
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(tcpPort);
    // Waiting for a client to connect
    System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
    Socket serverClientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("Connected to client " + serverClientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress());

    // tcpSocket = new Socket("localhost", tcpPort);
    // udpSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    // initialise all sockets
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(serverClientSocket.getOutputStream());
    in = new ObjectInputStream(serverClientSocket.getInputStream());
    connected = true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // System.err.println("Error connecting to " + addr + ":" + tcpPort);
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(0);
}

return connected;
```

}

public void createFile1(String serverRoute) { try { // fileName must be an api call returning value String fileName; fileName = "test.txt"; System.out.println("Creating file"); f = new File(serverRoute + "\" + fileName); // Creating the file FileOutputStream outToFile = new FileOutputStream(f); // Creating the stream

```
    receiveFile(serverRoute);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
}
```

}

public void testBlocker(String path) throws Exception { // while (true) { TransferInfo infoIn = new TransferInfo(); infoIn = (TransferInfo) in.readObject(); // if (infoIn == null) receiveFile(path); // } }

private FileOutputStream createFile(String fullPath) throws FileNotFoundException {

```
System.out.println("Creating file");
f = new File(fullPath); // Creating the file
return new FileOutputStream(f); // Creating the stream through which we write the file
```

}

// TODO public static void updateGUI(double percentageloaded) { // must update gui whenever percentage of packet changes // do something with percentage return; }

// receive file object public void receiveFile(String path) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException { System.out.println("Receiving file");

```
Map<Integer, byte[]> packetMap = new HashMap<>();
// Map<Integer, Entry<Action, Boolean>> actionMap = new HashMap<String,
// Entry<Action, Boolean>>();

// ArrayList<Integer> packetnumbersNotreceived = new ArrayList<Integer>();
TransferInfo infoIn = new TransferInfo();
TransferInfo infoOut = new TransferInfo();
missingpackets = false;
int burstSize = 0, numpack = 0;
double percentage = 0;
String filename = "";
totalfilesize = 0;

burstCounter = 0;
packetSize = 0;
// receive first tcp here with vital info
System.out.println("before first tcp");
try {
    
        infoIn = (TransferInfo) in.readObject();

    
    packetNumbers = infoIn.getPacketList();
    // totalNumPackets = packetNumbers.size();
    totalfilesize = infoIn.getFileSize();
    burstSize = infoIn.getBurstSize();
    filename = infoIn.getFileName();
    packetSize = infoIn.getPacketSize();
    // buffer = new byte[packetSize];
    // numpack = infoIn.getPacketList().size();
    System.out.println("packet num: " + packetNumbers + " totalfilesize : " + totalfilesize + " burstSize : "
            + burstSize + " " + "filename: " + filename);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}

packetNumbers = infoIn.getPacketList();

// totalNumPackets = packetNumbers.size();
// totalfilesize = infoIn.getFileSize();
// burstSize = infoIn.getBurstSize();
// filename = infoIn.getFileName();
// packetSize = infoIn.getPacketSize();
// buffer = new byte[packetSize];
// numpack = infoIn.getPacketList().size();

// Creates a new file with the filename at the specific path.
FileOutputStream outToFile = createFile(path + "\\" + infoIn.getFileName());

System.out.println("after first tcp");

if (infoIn.isTcp) {
    System.out.println("Receiving from TCp");

    ObjectInputStream ois = in;
    byte[] content = (byte[]) ois.readObject();
    Files.write(f.toPath(), content);
} else { // UDP Transfer
    // serverSocket.close();
    // connected = false;
    System.out.println("Receiving from UDP");
    // FileLength is total file size received from tcp

    while (totalBytesReceived < totalfilesize) {

        Thread tcpThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // r = 0;
                // problem receiving multiple different tcp
                try {
                    TransferInfo infoIn1 = new TransferInfo();
                    TransferInfo infoOut2 = new TransferInfo();
                    synchronized (in) {
                    infoIn1 = (TransferInfo) in.readObject();
                    }
                    packetNumbers = infoIn1.getPacketList();
                    connected1 = true;
                    // System.out.println("tcp received");
                    System.out.println("num times: " + k);
```

System.out.println("arraylist of packets that I should have receivedtest: " +infoIn1.getPacketList()); k++;

```
// give the inverse of the list received essentially
// this returns an arraylist with packets still needed
// packetNumbers is whats sent by Sender
// packetnumbersreceived is what user has received
        for (int i = 0; i < packetNumbers.size(); i++) {
        int element = packetNumbers.get(i);

        if (!packetnumbersreceived.contains(element)) {
        infoOut2.addPacket(element);
        System.out.println("this packet is missing" + element);

                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("\n\nleaving loop");

                    // if packets missing set boolean

    missingpackets = !infoOut2.getPacketList().isEmpty();
System.out.println("these packet are missing now\n" + infoOut2.getPacketList());

// communicate with sender regarding potential missing packets
// no problem sending multiple tcp and is received by sender
                    try {
                        System.out.println("r: " + r);
                        infoOut2.addPacket(r);
                        out.writeObject(infoOut2);
                        r++;
                        System.out.println("\nsending TCP\n");
                        // Thread.sleep(10000000);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    // receive all missing packets before continuing
                    while (missingpackets) {
                        System.out.println("\npackets are missing!!!\n");
try {
```

// plus 80 (exactly) needed to contain data and wrapper in packet buffer = new byte[packetSize + 94]; packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length); socket.receive(packet);

```
        byte[] receivedData = packet.getData();
        inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(receivedData);
        // will prob cause issues with mult objinputstr
        objInStream = new ObjectInputStream(inStream);
        receivedNumberedPacket = (numberedPacket) objInStream.readObject();
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }

            // socket.receive(packet);
            length = receivedNumberedPacket.getData().length;
            totalBytesReceived += length;
            burstCounter++;
                        packetnumbersreceived.add(receivedNumberedPacket.getId());
                        packetMap.put(receivedNumberedPacket.getId(), receivedNumberedPacket.getData());

                        // listen for packets that are sent
                try {
                synchronized (in) {
            infoIn1 (TransferInfo) in.readObject();

                            }
        packetNumbers = infoIn1.getPacketList();
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
```

// TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); }

```
    for (int i = 0; i < packetNumbers.size(); i++) {
        int element = packetNumbers.get(i);
    if (!packetnumbersreceived.contains(element)) {
    infoOut.addPacket(element);
                            }
    try {
        out.writeObject(infoOut);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
                            }
// if all missing packets received break out
    if (infoOut.getPacketList().isEmpty()) {
        missingpackets = false;
        break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
        System.out.println("support: " + in.markSupported());

                } catch (EOFException e) {
                    // Handle the end of the stream

                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException ioException) {
                        ioException.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // ...
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Handle the IO error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // Handle the class not found error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // System.out.println("end of thread");

            }
        });
        // try {
        // Thread.sleep(50);
        // } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // }
        System.out.println("listening for packets");
        // Receive packet and retrieve the data
        // System.out.println("\ntest before");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[packetSize + 94];
        // Arrays.fill(buffer, (byte) 0);
        packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, packetSize);
        // socket.receive(packet);

        // === modified ChatGPT code ==========
        try {
            // System.out.println("Packet Size: " + packetSize);
        // plus 80 (exactly) needed to contain data and wrapper in packet
            packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            // Arrays.fill(buffer, (byte) 0);

            socket.receive(packet);

            System.out.println("packetlength: " + packet.getLength());

            byte[] receivedData = packet.getData();
    ByteArrayInputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(receivedData);

            objInStream = new ObjectInputStream(inStream);
    receivedNumberedPacket = (numberedPacket) objInStream.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        // === modified ChatGPT code end =====

        burstCounter++;
        // packetnumbersreceived.add(packet.getOffset());
        
        packetnumbersreceived.add(receivedNumberedPacket.getId());
        
// System.out.println("ArrayList packetId received" + packetnumbersreceived);

        // packetMap.put(packet.getOffset(), packet);
        if (receivedNumberedPacket.getId() == 9) {
            packetnumbersreceived.remove(7);
        }
packetMap.put(receivedNumberedPacket.getId(), receivedNumberedPacket.getData());

        length = receivedNumberedPacket.getData().length;
        // int length1 = receivedNumberedPacket.getData().length;
        totalBytesReceived += (long) length;
        System.out.println("in main loop for receiving " + totalBytesReceived + " sizetotal " + totalfilesize);
        percentage = (double) totalBytesReceived / totalfilesize * 100;
        if (percentage > 100) {
            percentage = 100;
        }
        updateGUI(percentage);
        System.out.println("percentage received " + (int) percentage);
        // receive another tcp then compare what i have to what i need
        System.out.println("burst counter \n " + (burstCounter - 1));
        tcpThread.start();

        if (connected1) {
            System.out.println("tcps file received");
            // TransferInfo infoIn1 = new TransferInfo();
            // infoIn1 = (TransferInfo) in.readObject();
```

System.out.println("arraylist of packets that I should have received in connected1: " + infoIn.getPacketList()); // TCP has been received, wait for it to finish before continuing to receive // datagram packets // try { // tcpThread.join(); // } catch (InterruptedException e) { // e.printStackTrace(); // } } // tcpThread.interrupt();

```
        if (totalBytesReceived >= totalfilesize)
            tcpThread.interrupt();

    }
}
System.out.println("\nfinished");
// ChatGPT inspired, sorts all hashmap values regarding smallest packetid to
// largest, then writes to file. This is necessary if packets order is messed up
// Create a custom comparator to sort the HashMap by the offset value of the
// DatagramPacket
Comparator<Integer> offsetComparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {

    public int compare(Integer key1, Integer key2) {
        return key1.compareTo(key2);
    }
};

// Create a TreeMap with the custom comparator to sort the HashMap by offset
// value
Map<Integer, byte[]> sortedPacketMap = new TreeMap<Integer, byte[]>(
        offsetComparator);
sortedPacketMap.putAll(packetMap);

// Loop through the sorted TreeMap and write the data to file
for (Map.Entry<Integer, byte[]> entry : sortedPacketMap.entrySet()) {

    // DatagramPacket value = entry.getValue();
    outToFile.write(entry.getValue());
}
// socket.close();
outToFile.close();
// System.exit(0);
```

}

public static void updateGUI1(double percentageLoaded) { // must update gui whenever percentage of packet changes // do something with percentage // SenderGUIControl.updateProgressBar(percentageLoaded, bar, // senderLanding_pane); return; }

public static void main(String[] args) { String receiverAddress = "localhost"; int receiverUDPPort = 1234; int receiverTCPPort = 5678; try { Receiver test = new Receiver(receiverTCPPort, receiverUDPPort); test.connect();

```
    test.createFile1(receiverAddress);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

} ` This is the receiver class of a program that transfers udp files with tcp signalling. My current implementation is that the sender has a burst size of number of packets that they send, once they reach the burst size they must send a tcp (using TransferInfo object) to the receiver with an arraylist of packet numbers that should have been received, the receiver then sends a tcp back to to the sender with an arraylist of packetnumbers that they didnt receive but should have, if there are missing packets, they are resent and the process continues until all packages are receieved succesfully. Basically the burst size is used to signify how often missing packages should be looked for.

This program works when all packets are received succesfully, however the TCP that the receiver receives gets the first arraylist of packet numbers succesfully but subsequent TCP TransferInfoObjects are all the same.

synchronized (in) { infoIn1 = (TransferInfo) in.readObject(); } This works correctly when the burst size is first reached, the arraylist of packets received if the burst size is 3 would be Arraylist(1,2,3) but lets say I send 9 packets and the burst size is reached 3 times, I receive the same Arraylist(1,2,3) every burst size reached, when it should be Arraylist(1,2,3) iteration 1, Arraylist(1,2,3,4,5,6) iteration 2, Arraylist(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) iteration 3. Why is infoIn1 = (TransferInfo) in.readObject(); reading in the same object and not receiving the new object correctly, I've checked sender side and it does send the correct packetnumbers via tcp theyre just no received. Please Help.TransferInfo infoOut1 = new TransferInfo(); //add packet to arraylist to send, would add 1 to arraylist for eg infoOut1.addPacket(1);

```
                System.out.println("packets sent " + infoOut1.getPacketList());
                out.writeObject(infoOut1);

                out.flush();`
```

Comment: I'm not going to read through your code dump, especially as you haven't formatted it, but it may be useful to know that if you write the same object twice to an ObjectOutputStream, the fields of the object are only written the first time, subsequently a reference to the first object is written. See the javadoc for `writeObject` and `reset`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).